# Does replacing passes in Passbook require new pass to be different than the old one?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, passbook

I'm trying to update a pass in Passbook by calling `-replacePassWithPass:` and passing exactly the same pass that already is in `PKPassLibrary`. Method returns with `NO` (replacing failed) - why? (BTW: console on my device doesn't show any logs from iOS)

The docs for `-replacePassWithPass:` are not very helpful in that case:

> This will fail if a pass with matching identifier and serial number is
>   not already present in the library, or if the process is not entitled
>   to access the pass.

and:

> YES if the pass was replaced successfully; otherwise NO.

I fullfil both requirements.

Is it not possible to replace passes in that way? Should I use `-removePass:` and than try to add it with `PKAddPassesViewController`?

My backend does not support updating passes yet, so I cannot verify all posibilities here (i.e. really get updated pass with same typeID and serialNumber, but different content). What are your experiences?

Comment: What's the reason that you need to replace a pass with exactly the same pass?  It seems like in that case you should just leave the pass alone.

Answer (score 1):

As long as passTypeIdentifier **and** serial number of one pass equal to passTypeIdentifier **and** serial number of another pass - they are instances of the same pass. If everything is the same between two passes - they are one instance of one pass.

If you do have the pass in your PKPassLibrary, **-replacePassWithPass** works in the first case, **-removePass** and adding it back with **PKAddPassesViewController** does in the second one.

Updating passes is always a replacement. There are basically three requirements you have to fulfill in order to successfully replace the pass:

1) a pass with the same passTypeIdentifier and serialNumber must be already added to your PKPassLibrary;

2) the new instance of the pass must have at least one difference to the old pass (except passTypeIndentifier and serialNumber which must remain the same);

3) your app must have an entitlement for passes with this passTypeIdentifier.